# VBA VLookup Method not working for both numbers and strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook full of product codes and names. Contained within a form are various text boxes where a user can enter a code and its corresponding label will update with the name found in the workbook. Each text box runs the following sub when changed

```
Private Sub FindItem(x As Long)

Dim Name As Variant

Name = Application.VLookup(AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x).Text, Sheet1.Range("B:C"), 2, False)
If IsError(Name) Then
 AddStockForm.Controls("Name" & x).Caption = "Unknown Code"
Else
 AddStockForm.Controls("Name" & x).Caption = Name
End If

End Sub
```

The sub takes the user input in the target box (e.g. Code1) and finds the corresponding name and writes it to the label (e.g. Name1). HOWEVER, the product codes are either strings, alphanumeric and plain text, OR numbers. For stupid reasons beyond my control, some codes have to be numbers, others have to contain letters.

This code works PERFECTLY for any code with a character in it (MYCODE or 500A) but not numbers, it writes "Unknown code" for any number, and they are in the lookup range. I have searched around stackoverflow and answers suggest declaring as variants, I've done this, even by assigning `Controls().Text`  as a variant before using it in VLookup. I suspect the problem is

```
AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x).Text
```

is a string. But I cannot convert to an INT because the user input might be a number or string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried saving the input into a variable and then checken whether the variable `Isnumeric`? Depending on the result you can then cast it as an integer or keep using it as a string.

Comment: hi. are all cells of the workbook formated has text or the cells with only number are in a format numeric ?

Comment: If you read out the text from the control, but search in a range where the numbers you're searching for are stored as integers, it will not work and return a not found due to the type not matching what you're looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear, the data in the table you are doing the lookup against may be either a string or an integer? A quick and dirty fix could be to do something along the lines of IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F1&"",$A$1:$B$3,2,0),VLOOKUP(--F1,$A$1:$B$3,2,0)) however I'd be more inclined to avoid using vlookup in my code in general

Comment: Yes I have tried testing with Isnumeric, converted to INT or SNG, and searched again, but still doesn't work. I have tried multiple formatting solutions. Strangely, even if I format number codes as text in the workbook it still doesn't work. (Not a solution as these must be formatted as numbers)

Comment: Also, this issue aside I am extremely happy with Vlookup, it's doing exactly what i want with no loopy performance deficit (this workbook is gonna be big)

Comment: @David That is not the malfunctioning part. x is a variable used to find the correct textbox and label, so FindItem(2) would update Name2 with the search result of Code2. As the function is working for stringy codes, I know this part is working fine.

Comment: @Dave played around with it and -- crashes the code. I can't assign it to a variable and then use -- as it needs to do it during the lookup if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you not just tell Excel to store everything in the source sheet as text, even the numeric codes? You'd have to write a routine to run through the sheet and add a ' prefix to each number - but you'd only have to do it once

Comment: @HarassedDad Sadly not because arithmetic is performed on some of the product codes. This part is not my design. :(

Comment: @David The value of Name will always be a string, this string is found by looking up either a number or string. There are no issues assigning anything to .Caption, it's either Name or "Unknown Code". It has never had an error assigning this caption. The problem is, if I have a product code 1000 with name Fred, if I type 1000 it will come back with "Unknown Code". But if the product code is 1000A for example it will come back with "Fred". And I've checked cell formatting, converted ints to strings and strings to ints, and all the above and it will not find numbers in the range.

Comment: @David you are misunderstanding the code. Each text field has the name CodeX, and X is just used to select the appropriate text field and label. The VALUE of that text field is then used to search. So the user might input "1000" into Code1, and then it should update Name1.Caption with the vlookup result. This works perfectly for "1000A" for example, but not for "1000". The x part has nothing to do with the problem in question. Ignore it.

Comment: The formula I gave was just as an example to try and prompt you into how to convert it for your own use. If you want a more complete example, does this work for you?     name = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x) & "", Sheet1.Range("B:C"), 2, False), Application.VLookup(AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x) * 1, Sheet1.Range("B:C"), 2, False))

Comment: @Dave Yes that is more or less what I tried, I tried a few ways of forcing int or str, none have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create a separate function which has the separate parts you want to do. In this instance, we are checking the input value first. If this is numerical we want to try doing the lookup as a string, then as a number if that fails. If the input value is not numerical we can go ahead and do the lookup as normal.

```
Public Function lookupStringOrInt(inputValue As Variant, tableArray As Range, colIndexNum As Long, Optional rangeLookup As Boolean) As Variant

    If IsNumeric(inputValue) Then
        lookupStringOrInt = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(inputValue & "", tableArray, colIndexNum, rangeLookup), Application.VLookup(inputValue * 1, tableArray, colIndexNum, rangeLookup))
    Else
        lookupStringOrInt = Application.VLookup(inputValue, tableArray, colIndexNum, rangeLookup)
    End If

End Function
```

You can then call this in your code with the line

```
name = lookupStringOrInt(AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x) & "", Sheet1.Range("B:C"), 2, False)
```

If the value you are looking for does not exist, the function will return 'Error 2042'. You can choose to handle this however you like.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be working. Just a note if others follow this code, the solution's inputValue should be `AddStockForm.Controls("Code" & x).Text`, specifically the text within the text field. Thanks for your time. (I would have tried this but I tried much the same thing within the original sub and didn't work)